# How to use re.sub to match and substitute any numbers after - extension?

Tags: python, regex

I want to substitute from **'datasets/4/image-3.jpg'** to **'datasets/4/image-1.jpg'**. Are there any ways to do it by using re.sub? Or should I try something else like .split("/")[-1]? I had tried below but end up getting **'datasets/1/image-1.jpg'**, but I want to keep the **/4/** instead of **/1/**.

**My Code**

```
import re
employee_name = 'datasets/4/image-3.jpg'
label = re.sub('[0-9]', "1", employee_name)
print(label)
```

**Output**

```
datasets/1/image-1.jpg
```

**Expected Input**

```
datasets/4/image-3.jpg
```

**Expected Output**

```
datasets/4/image-1.jpg
```

Comment: `re.sub` is not necessary, `employee_name.replace('-3.jpg', '-1.jpg')` looks sufficient here. If you need to match *any number* after `-` and before the extension, please edit the question.

Comment: There are 2 expected outputs and first one is just same as the original input.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ya I need to match any number after -

Comment: Then use `re.sub(r'-\d+\.jpg', '-1.jpg', text)` then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'-\d+\.jpg', '-1.jpg', text)
```

**Note**: If the match is always at the end of string, append the `$` anchor at the end of the regex. If there can be other text after and you need to make sure there are no word chars after `jpg`, add a word boundary, `\b`. If you want to match other extensions, use a group, e.g. `(?:jpe?g|png)`.

**Regex details**

- `-\d+` - one or more digits
- `\.jpg` - `.jpg` string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EPRAtz/1) ([code generator link](https://regex101.com/r/EPRAtz/1/codegen?language=python)).